# maven multi web module

Tags: maven-2

I have multi module web application(m1,m2, m3, final). Module "final" is a web module and dependants on m1,m2 and m3. "m1,m2 and m3" are web modules. I need modules m1,m2, m3 resources and jsps should be copied "final" module's target dir. Need your help.

Comment: Did you try writing the pom files? Can you put the relevent snippets here?

Comment: Yes, writing pom files. Please add your snippets too.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called [overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) and is documented. So please read the posted link first.